# Data too long for column - Rails 4 migrations cancelled

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a migration initially as below

```
class Createfriends < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friends do |t|
      t.string :FirstName
      t.string :LastName
      t.string :MiddleName
      t.string :Gendre
      t.string :Email
      t.string :ImageUrl
      t.string :Country
      t.string :City
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then i need to change the type of ImageUrl as someone can load send the path of link which may exceed 255 characters so i made another migration as below

```
class ChangeImageUrlInWaiter < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :friends, :ImageUrl , :text
  end

  def down
    change_column :friends ,:ImageUrl , :string
  end
end
```

Now when I try to rollback all migrations using

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

It throws me error

> rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, all later
>   migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'ImageUrl' at row 1: ALTER
>   TABLE `waiters` CHANGE `ImageUrl` `ImageUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL

Reason is clear that There is data present in ImageUrl which is more than 255 , Now the question is how to overcome this problem saving the data  or even if have to loss some of data

Comment: One way it's update an ImageUrl column before change it type.

Comment: @Зелёный can you explain please

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with truncating your data, then just issue an `UPDATE` query before changing the schema back to `255` chars.

Don't use [ActiveRecord in migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045440/migrating-data-not-just-schema-rails), it's hard to get it right and may bring you different types of issues. So, you need this:

```
  def down
    execute 'UPDATE friends SET ImageUrl = SUBSTR(ImageUrl, 1, 255)'
    change_column :friends, :ImageUrl, :string
  end
```